# Отключение скролла

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

У меня на каком то объекте имеется событие `onmousewheel`

```
<input type="number" min="0" max="23" step="1" required="required" placeholder="hour" name="s_hour" value="13" onmousewheel="foo(this,event)">
```

Мы видим, что при срабатывании колеса на объекте срабатывает функция `foo(obj,event)`.

И тут возникает 3 вопроса

1. Как сделать так, чтобы при срабатывании колеса, страница, а точнее `<div>` с `overflow:scroll` не прокручивалась(-лся) ни вниз, ни вверх?
2. Как узнать, в какую сторону сработало колесо (вверх/вниз)?
3. Как узнать на сколько оно сработало (на 1 прокрутку вниз, на 2 прокрутки вверх)?

Знаю, есть на jQuery хороший плагин jquery.mousewheel, но мне нужен не плагин.

Скролл нужно не убрать, а "заморозить", чтобы он не сработал

Помогите, пожалуйста!

З.Ы. главное, чтобы работало в Google Chrome.

Comment: Я могу предполагать, что события:
wheelDelta,
wheelDeltaX,
wheelDeltaY,

То что мне нужно. Но он дает значения 120 или -120

Comment: [Событие onscroll, как узнать в какую сторону крутят колесо?](http://hashcode.ru/questions/117830/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
onscroll="return false"
```

Comment: На один вопрос отвечено.
Но поправлю
onmousewheel="foo(this,event);return false"

Answer (score 0):

> Скролл нужно не убрать, а
>   "заморозить", чтобы он не сработал

Важно помнить, что прокруткой страницы можно управлять еще стрелками и пробелом!

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770025/how-to-disable-scrolling-temporarily) что можно нагуглить по запросу *disable scrollbar*.

Comment: Вы плохо прочли вопрос. По поводу заморозки все улажено return'ом